# How to create a Average measure on a aggregated table of both rows and columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

So I have this
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djEEH.png)

My wanted result is to create a measure that is a Average of the Value 1 + value 2, split by date and Type

I have created a legit solution with a calculated table

```
consolidateTable = 
SUMMARIZE('Blad2';Blad2[Type];Blad2[Date];"summarized";sum(Blad2[value 1]) + sum(Blad2[Value 2]))
```

and the result looks like this:
[SummarizedTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PARsj.png)

with the measure

```
measure = AVERAGE(consolidateTable[summarized])
```

I get the wanted
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAib0.png)

I want to create the whole process in a measure
I'm happy for any input in how to create this measure piece by piece with first filtering the table.

Comment: Are you looking for a calculated table or measure to use in a visualization? Is it AVERAGE (Value 1 + Value 2)? If so, the AVERAGE(Value 1 + Value 2) should be 385 for CAR and 374 for HOUSE? Please, add more details in your question.

Comment: Okay. My little advice until I get back. Using a table visual you can get the AVERAGE (Value 1 + Value 2) for any combination of filters (Date, Type ... ) with a measure like this one: AVERAGE 1 + 2 : = AVERAGEX ( Blad2, Blad2[value 1] + Blad2[value 2] )